# Spring and MongoDB. Find last stored object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to know how can a find last object which was stored on db (latest). My object is save with timeStamp so I can  use this value to recognized which is latest if this will be necessarily, so function in repository  may be looks like

```
@Repository
public interface MyObjectRepository extends MongoRepository<MyObject, String> {

    MyObject findByNameAndTimesmapt(String name, int timestamp); // I want to get here latest object
}
```

And Object

```
public class MyObject {
    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    @Field("timestamp")
    private int timestamp;

    public MyObject(String name, int timestamp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

My function should be give me this same result as command

`db.foo.find("name" : "someName"}).sort({"timestamp":-1}).one();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this. This will get you results the way shell query does. Both the below variants should work.

```
MyObject findFirstByNameOrderByTimestampDesc(String name);
```

Or

```
MyObject findTopByNameOrderByTimestampDesc(String name);
```

Comment: Exacly I looked this. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this method:

```
findFirstByOrderByIdDesc()
```

No need to store the object's timestamp in the collection.

Refer to [Spring's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) for more details.